# D3 highlight corresponding table entry when hovering over donut chart slice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I started working with D3 and had a little help yesterday getting some code to work. I have one new quick question. I have a donut chart representing some soon to be JSON object. When you hover over some of the pieces of the chart, they animate and pop out. There is a corresponding table that is populated by the same object. I was able to get the data in the table mapped out so that when you hover over the data, it animates the corresponding pie chart slice. I'm trying to get it to work in the opposite way as well, so that when you hover over the donut slice, it highlights the table.

Currently, I have it highlighting the entire table, but I can't seem to figure out how to map it to the individual and correct table entry.

[Fiddle for context](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianAllen/t2Lep1yz/3/)

My arc mouseover, where I currently have it highlighting everything,

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
                d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
                    .duration(100)
                    .attr("d", arcOver);
                var path = paths[0][i];

                  d3.selectAll("#testtable .dataRow")
                    .style("background-color","red");
```

Can someone provide a little help on how to map to the correct table entry?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since your pie chart and table are ordered the same, you can do it by index:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
    d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
        .duration(100)
        .attr("d", arcOver);
    var row  = d3.selectAll("#testtable .dataRow")[0][i]; // i is the index
    d3.select(row)
        .style("background-color","red");  
})
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2Lep1yz/8/).